# How can I add the port to iptables rules on centos?

Tags: centos, iptables

I want to open the port 8040 on my centos, but I keep getting connection refused.

This is what I have done:

```
iptables -I INPUT -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 8040 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
/etc/init.d/iptables save
sudo service iptables restart
```

---

```
sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:8040
acctboth   all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

---

```
telnet localhost  8040
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
```

What else do I need to do?

Update:

I tried disabling iptables and selinux, I still get connection refused.

Comment: iptables --flush 
If you do that all rules will be deleted.  If it still fails you have a firewall or something else,not on this computer, is blocking you.

Comment: Have you checked the state of the port with netstat, to make sure it's listening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *connection refused* message indicates that there is no service on that port, not that a firewall is blocking it. You must have a listening TCP socket on that port (daemon, server, netcat). Besides, your POLICY is ACCEPT, so anything would get through anyway.

Comment: [ref](http://www.pcvr.nl/tcpip/tcp_conn.htm)